# Clearing Ionic History so ionNavBackButton isn't Displayed Not Working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an intro of slides before the user is redirected to login, but when I switch to the login the back history is displayed, and I'd rather it wasn't.  Using $ionicHistory.clearHistory() before changing state doesn't appear to do anything, and the back button is still displayed.

```
.controller( 'IntroController', [ '$scope', '$state', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', '$ionicHistory',
    function( $scope, $state, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicHistory ) {

        // Skip the introduction, and redirect to login
        $scope.skipIntro = function() {

            $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
            $state.go( 'login.index' );
        };

        ...

    } ] )
```

Other than just hiding the back button using CSS on the login, which seems like a UI hack, can this be achieved through the Ionic API?

**UPDATE**

For now I'm using

```
hide-back-button="true"
```

on the ion-view, but even though this works I'd still like to know how clear the browser history for other parts of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your back button use `nav-clear` directive. This will clear navigation stack history.

Comment: Seems like `nav-clear` is no longer present in ionic 1.0.0!? At least I cannot find it in the source-code.